# itext7 not creating new pdf-page automatically

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

When I add multiple Tables to an iText7 pdf and the number of Tables are more than fits in one page the following exception gets thrown.

> Exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
>   Source: "itext.layout" StackTrace: "at
>   iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer.Layout(LayoutContext
>   layoutContext)
>                at iText.Layout.Renderer.RootRenderer.AddChild(IRenderer renderer)
>                at iText.Layout.RootElement`1.Add[T2](BlockElement`1 element)
>                at iText.Layout.Document.Add[T](BlockElement`1 element)
>                at iTextSharp7_Test.Controllers.PdfController.ReplicateBug(String
>   pdfFile) in C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\App_Test\iTextSharp7_Test\Controllers\PdfController.cs:line
>   443"

In the provided example the exception gets thrown when the 6th table is about to be added.

The only way I have been able to handle this issue is by assuming that the exception is thrown by adding more data to the pdf than fits in one page and add a new page within the try catch block, a solution that is very ugly and not good in the long term.

Example:

```
public void ReplicateBug(string pdfFile)
{
    iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter writer = null;
    iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf = null;
    iText.Layout.Document document = null;

    try
    {
        writer = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(pdfFile);
        pdf = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(writer);
        document = new iText.Layout.Document(pdf, iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize.A4);
        document.Add(new iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph("*** PRODUCTS ***"));
        iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Draw.DashedLine dashedLine = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Draw.DashedLine();
        document.Add(new iText.Layout.Element.LineSeparator(dashedLine));

        iText.Layout.Element.Table table = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            iText.Layout.Element.Cell cell = null;

            table = new iText.Layout.Element.Table(2);
            table.SetMarginTop(10);

            cell = new iText.Layout.Element.Cell().Add("-- PRODUCT --");
            table.AddCell(cell);
            cell = new iText.Layout.Element.Cell(3, 1).Add("image");
            cell.SetHorizontalAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            cell.SetVerticalAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
            table.AddCell(cell);
            cell = new iText.Layout.Element.Cell().Add("Product text." + Environment.NewLine + "Welcome");
            cell.SetHeight(75);
            table.AddCell(cell);
            cell = new iText.Layout.Element.Cell().Add((i + 1).ToString().PadLeft(10, '0'));
            table.AddCell(cell);

            try
            {
                document.Add(table);
                document.Add(new iText.Layout.Element.LineSeparator(dashedLine));   // Default LineWidth is 1
            }
            catch
            {
                // NOTE: After adding 5 tables to the pdf an exception is thrown of the following kind.

                // Exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
                // Source: "itext.layout"
                // StackTrace: "at iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer.Layout(LayoutContext layoutContext)
                //              at iText.Layout.Renderer.RootRenderer.AddChild(IRenderer renderer)
                //              at iText.Layout.RootElement`1.Add[T2](BlockElement`1 element)
                //              at iText.Layout.Document.Add[T](BlockElement`1 element)
                //              at iTextSharp7_Test.Controllers.PdfController.ReplicateBug(String pdfFile) in C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\App_Test\\iTextSharp7_Test\\Controllers\\PdfController.cs:line 443"
            }
        }

        document.Close();
        pdf.Close();
        writer.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        if (document != null)
        {
            document.Close();
        }

        if (pdf != null)
        {
            pdf.Close();
        }

        if (writer != null)
        {
            writer.Close();
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

This issue has already been fixed in `7.0.2` (and `7.0.2-SNAPSHOT`, which is known as `7.0.1.1` in `.NET` version). The snapshot NuGet package can be downloaded from [Artifactory](https://repo.itextsupport.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/nuget/itext7/). The `7.0.2` release version will be available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/) in nearest weeks.